# The Entity Framework is not installed On Project 'xxx'

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a project using Entity Framework 6.2.0, .NET Framework 4.6.2.
I did some changes on database models and I wanted to make migration.
However I got the error below on the Package Manager Console

[image]

I'm wondering how is that possible?

-"Package is already exist in this project"

-"Entity Framework package is not installed".

I tried those:

-Removed EF package and installed again

-Did Clean,build,rebuild all solution and the all projects one by one

-Removed all packages from solution and restored those again

After try 'update package reinstall' , I got that:

[image]

PS: That's not the first migration. I have been working on this project over 1 year.

Comment: have you tried this : Update-Package –reinstall this restore all package or for specific package Update-Package –reinstall <package_name>

Comment: I uploaded a picture to my question, you can check this @PranayRana

Comment: open the Project file directly, remove the reference to the package, then try an install from nuget after that, but before trying to install again unload and re-load the solution.

Comment: Let's recap. Instead of updating, you tried to install a package that already was there, got an error obviously. Removed all packages and then tried to update a package that was not there, right? Got another error, cause the package was no longer there.

Comment: I've tried all of them but they're not successfull